# why should I use backbone.js or spine.js

Tags: javascript, architecture, backbone.js, spine.js

I'm developing a mostly informational public facing website.  My architecture is to deliver JSON data to the client for pages in the site.  I plan on caching the JSON in localStorage on client and let it persist there for XX amount of time before it refreshes.  I'm using client side templates (jsRender) for rendering JSON into UI widgets that are then pushed into view using jQuery.

In my research for this, I stumbled upon JavaScript MVC approaches like backbone.js and spine.js among others.  I've read through them and am comparing them to my approach above and am not sure if/why I would need something like backbone.js or spine.js.  I'm not doing hardly any data entry except having users fill out contact us form or sign up for our newsletter.  So, really no need to keep view and model in sync.  I'm just retrieving JSON from my server and rendering it using templates and caching JSON for a period of time in localStorage.

I want to check with the experts out there if my approach seems appropriate and to see if I really "need" backbone.js or spine.js.  How would any of these approaches help with my architectural direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you feel you don't need anything else, I would suggest not to use it. "Premature optimization is a root of all evil". When you will run into trouble because your application becomes messy and you spend a lot of time implementing new features or solving bugs then all this stuff will start to make sense to you. Then you will learn why it's very convinient and elegant to implement MVC in your app from the very begining.